# Unable to do rsync with find command

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to do rsync from destination server to remote server with sshpass and find command I'm using the below command but it's failed,
command:

```
sshpass -p password@1 find . -type f -name "*"`date -d '1 day ago' '+%Y-%m-%d'`"*" | rsync -avH root@10.31.0.0:/var/lib/edb/as12/data/log .
```

I Tried the below command but failed to do rsync from destination server to remote server facing problem to use find command with rsync. I want to do search the particular pattern files and then rsync those files to destination server.

command:

```
sshpass -p password@1 find . -type f -name ""date -d '1 day ago' '+%Y-%m-%d'"" | rsync -avH root@10.31.0.0:/var/lib/edb/as12/data/log .
```

Answer (score -1):

O correto está abaixo

sshpass -p senha@1 find . -type f -name "data -d '1 dia atrás' '+%Y-%m-%d'" | rsync -avH root@10.31.0.0:/var/lib/edb/as12/data/log .